# Owl Carousel Event from Click or Autoplay

Tags: javascript, dom-events, owl-carousel

Trying to find a way to differentiate between [Owl Carousel 2.0 Events](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html) (`translate`, or `change`) that were **triggered by a mouse click** vs. **triggered by an autoplay event**.

I would be extra grateful for an answer which approaches the question in a more general form– For an event which can be simultaneously trigger by the user and a `setInterval`, are there any properties of the event which can help to differentiate the source?

[Example Set Up](http://jsfiddle.net/jn67faot/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean to track when the carousel is clicked.

```
var clicked = false;

$('.carousel').click(function() {
    clicked = true;
  $(this).trigger('next.owl.carousel');
});

$('.carousel').on('change.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  if (clicked) {
    clicked = false;
    $('.info').text('click');
  } else {
    $('.info').text('autoplay');
  }
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jn67faot/

Answer (score 0):

I presume you were doing this in an attempt to add some logic into the autoplay event.

In case you were, I was able to accomplish this by doing the following.

Within the owl.carousel.js file you will find autoplay events.
In my particular case, I was looking to add functionality to the end of the autoplay processing.

```
Autoplay.prototype._next = function(speed) {

// Native Carousel Logic


// Additional Custom Code here

}
```